# ng serve commands - running from two different domains

Tags: bash, angular-cli

i got an interesting challenging situation.

I have two domains:
`example1.com`, `example1.co.uk`

when I run :

```
ng serve --host exempla1.co.uk --port 80
```

When I am trying to access the page from `example1.com` it gives me a specific error for ng serve command.

How shall I write the bash command to include both domains?

Comment: ng serve is a development-only server. Don't use it in production. Just us ng build --prod, and serve the content of the generated dist directory with aproduction web server supporting virtual host configuration (apache, nginx, etc.)

Comment: Thank you Sir appreciate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is very simple

```
-prod --aot --host example1.com --port 80 --disable-host-check
```

WARNING Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION USE!